Need Help Migrating Python Azure Functions to an Azure VM
I'm currently trying to migrate five Python-based Azure Functions (which are deployed as HTTPS endpoints) to run on an Azure Virtual Machine instead of using Azure Functions I aim to migrate my existing Python scripts from Azure Functions to an Azure VM, manage HTTPS endpoints on the VM, configure the necessary environment and dependencies.
My main question is:
Do I need to create a separate server using a web framework like Flask, or can I run the scripts exactly like Azure Functions as separate scripts with HTTPS endpoints?
Any insights or recommendations on the best approach would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

why do you need to put your function on a VM ???

I would need the GPU support.

uou could use container app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-custom-container?tabs=core-tools%2Cacr%2Cazure-cli2%2Cazure-cli&pivots=container-apps. It has an option for Gpu: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/blog/appsonazureblog/introducing-serverless-gpus-on-azure-container-apps/4288571

Yes, you need a web framework like Flask or FastAPI to expose HTTP endpoints on the Azure VM, because the Azure VM will not automatically manage HTTP requests and routing for you as Azure Functions do.
